# Too many browser.wait calls in protractorjs

Tags: javascript, selenium, asynchronous, selenium-webdriver, protractor

My test steps to test a logout flow are,

1) click a logout button

2) wait for url change to login.html

3) wait for login page text fields to be loaded.

Code looks like,

```
//wait for logout menu/button    
browser.wait(function(){
  return element(by.buttonText('Log out')).isPresent()
})
element(by.buttonText('Log out')).click()
//wait for url to change to login.html
browser.wait(function(){
  return browser.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url){
    return url.indexOf("login") != -1
  })
})
//wait for login page text boxes
browser.wait(function(){
  return element(by.css('[type=text]')).isPresent()
})
```

This makes my code lengthy since, i am wrapping each action inside a `browser.wait` call. 
Is there a way i can avoid `browser.wait`. I tried adding,

```
browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000)
```

But then, i get `No element found using locator: by.buttonText("Log out")` error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Protractor has inbuilt [`ExpectedConditions`](https://angular.github.io/protractor/#/api?view=ExpectedConditions) checks, you don't have to write a custom function yourself all the time. Here's how to wait for an element to be visible -

```
var EC = protractor.ExpectedConditions;
browser.wait(EC.presenceOf(element(by.buttonText('Log out'))), 10000); //Checks only if element is present in DOM
browser.wait(EC.visibilityOf(element(by.buttonText('Log out'))), 10000); //Checks if element is present in DOM and visible to user on page
```

You can also create a custom function as shown in another answer. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing the same thing more than once, it tends to help to make a helper function for it. Add to your helper file something like:

```
this.waiterFunc = function(element){
        browser.wait(function() {
            return element.isPresent();
        })
    };
```

then in your main class you can do things like:
    helper.waiterFunc(element(by.buttonText('Log out')));

Im not sure about avoiding browser.wait as its an integral step in the process of waiting for the elements to be accessible at a particular time. If you dont wait, then you are going to start getting nasty "element not clickable at time x" errors